# Struggling with Class Inheritance & super().__init__

Tags: python, inheritance

Very new to Python, trying to create a game in which any number of armies can be created, but each army will pre-render the names of the soldiers.

I think I need to be using super init to really cut down on duplicate code, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it work. From what I understand my class `Army` should be the Parent class, with `RedArmy` and `Scout` as subclasses. I'm just struggling to understand where the `super().__init__()` should come in?

```
class Army:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = None
        self.scoutname = None
        self.demomanname = None
        self.medicname = None

    def train_scout(self, weapon):
        return Scout(self.color, self.scoutname, weapon)

class RedArmy(Army):

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = "Red"
        self.scoutname = "Yankee"
        self.demomanname = "Irish"
        self.medicname = "Dutch"

class BlueArmy(Army):
    pass

class Scout:
    specialization = "fast captures"

    def __init__(self, color, scoutname, weapon):
        self.color = color
        self.scoutname = scoutname
        self.weapon = weapon

    def introduce(self):
        return (f'Hi I\'m {self.scoutname}, I do {self.specialization} and I wield a {self.weapon}')


my_army = RedArmy()    
soldier_1 = my_army.train_scout("baseball bat")
print(soldier_1.introduce())
```

Comment: NOTE: if using Python-2.7, define the base class as `class Army(object)`, otherwise super() won't work. Using `newclass(object)` is OK on Python 3, as well.

Comment: @LeoK The OP is obviously using Python 3; if not, `super()` won't work anyway. And it's counterproductive to teach novices how to write new, Python-3-only code as dual-version code instead, since that means missing out on all of the improvements of Python 3.

Comment: @LeoK If using Python 2.7, the f-string in `Scout.introduce` will cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where to put the `super().__init__` (if anywhere) depends on the specifics of your class hierarchy.

Most commonly, if it matters where you put it, you want it at the very start of the subclass's `__init__` method. This makes sure that all of the base-class variables are set up, all of its invariants are met, and all of its methods can be called by the rest of the subclass `__init__` code.

In your case, it matters because you're setting the same attributes in the base class and the subclass. You obviously want the subclass version to be the one that takes, so it has to come after the default assignments, not before:

```
class RedArmy(Army):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = "Red"
        self.scoutname = "Yankee"
        self.demomanname = "Irish"
        self.medicname = "Dutch"
```

---

However, it's worth considering whether you really want the base class to set these variables to `None` in the first place.

I assume that in your real code, `BlueArmy` isn't just going to `pass`, but is instead going to do the same thing as `RedArmy`, replacing all of those values with some strings.

Also, the rest of your code is presumably going to assume that there are valid strings there, not `None`. An exception like `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'` is harder to debug than `AttributeError: 'GreenArmy' object has no attribute 'scoutname'`, not easier, so why not just leave the defaults out? Then you can eliminate `Army.__init__` entirely, and you don't have to worry about calling `super` in the subclass initializers in the first place.

Or, alternatively, you could have `Army.__init__` take parameters that are used to assign the values, and have the subclasses call `super().__init__("Red", "Yankee", "Irish", "Dutch")`. Then, `Army()` will raise a `TypeError` instead of creating an invalid `Army` instance. Or you could make an `@abstractmethod` named `self._setup()` that `Army.__init__` calls and expects each subclass to provide, so `Army()` will raise an even more meaningful `TypeError` about instantiating an abstract class. These refinements make it easier to debug your `Army` subclasses—if you just have two of them, they may just be a waste of time, but if you have a bunch of them, which will be developed by a variety of people or over a long period of time, it might be worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Passing values as arguments makes the most sense if you want your classes to take advantage of `super` and `init`:

```
class Army:    
    def __init__(self, color=None, scoutname=None, demomanname=None,
                 medicname=None):
        self.color = color
        self.scoutname = scoutname
        self.demomanname = demomanname
        self.medicname = medicname

    def train_scout(self, weapon):
        return Scout(self.color, self.scoutname, weapon)


class RedArmy(Army):
    def __init__(self, color="Red", scoutname="Yankee", demomanname="Irish",
                 medicname="Dutch"):
        super().__init__(color, scoutname, demomanname, medicname)


class Scout:
    specialization = "fast captures"

    def __init__(self, color, scoutname, weapon):
        self.color = color
        self.scoutname = scoutname
        self.weapon = weapon

    def introduce(self):
        return (
            f'Hi I\'m {self.scoutname}, I do {self.specialization} and I wield '
            f'a {self.weapon}')


my_army = RedArmy()    
soldier_1 = my_army.train_scout("baseball bat")
print(soldier_1.introduce())
```